# HTML path for external files

Tags: html, css, path

I want to know what is the difference between `./` and `../` when we are giving path. Is it same?

Comment: Re bounty: What detail is missing?

Comment: Re change in accepted answer: Why did you accept an answer that doesn't address the question?

Comment: and why not Google this? simple "difference between ./ and ../ paths" search got this awesome article : http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no difference between below given example both are same

```
./myfiles/images

../myfiles/images
```

This ./myfiles/images is the image folder here, and this ../myfiles/images is the parent directory which is myfiles folder here

So ../myfiles/images is like we want image from the images folder. This ./myfiles/images is the same of image both are get from the image folder here.

Comment: `./` and `/` do not mean the same thing. They will give the same result only when the URI has only one `/` character between the host name and the query string or fragment id.

Comment: The question is asking about `./` and `../` not `./` and `/`.

Comment: After edits: You are now talking about the correct set of things. However,  The first paragraph is still just plain wrong. The last two paragraphs are incomprehensible. "is the image folder here" — Where is "here"? "the parent directory which is myfiles folder here" — The parent directory of what? "myfiles" is a subdirectory of some unspecified directory. You have no starting point so you can't compare the URIs.

Comment: ../ and ./ are same? suppose you are here in `here` folder. you say, `./boo.jpg` it's still in same `here` folder and `boo.jpg` is child of `here` folder; but if you do: `../boo.jpg` it's in parent folder, and `boo.jpg` is now a sibling of `here` folder.

Answer (score 11):

`.` is the current directory

`..` is the parent directory

So from `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz.html`:

`./x` is `http://example.com/foo/bar/x`

`../x` is `http://example.com/foo/x`

Comment: we can access current directory without using ./ so why we use it

Answer (score 1):

`./` is the current directory, `../` is the parent directory of the current directory

Answer (score 1):

This `./` is the current directory, and this `../` is the parent directory.

So this:`../hello.png` mean: get hello.png from the parent directory.
This `./hello.png` is the same of `hello.png`; both are get from the current directory

Answer (score 0):

`./` reference to your current directory while `../` reference to the parent  and so on `../../`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding `./` is the same directory. `../` traverses backwards through a directory structure.

example:  working directory: `\drives\letters\numbers`

`./` is the numbers dir
`../` from numbers will take you to letters dir
`../../` from numbers will take to the drives dir

and you keep adding `../` to go backwards until you are in the right place.